# Update a String value in hashmap

Tags: java, android, android-listview, arraylist, hashmap

I have a hashmap that will get data every time I selected a row of item from other hashmap. And I have do a checking in arraylist before the data stored into the hashmap. This checking is to check whether the itemID is exists in arraylist. If yes, I want to change the value of quantity for the itemID that is exist in the arraylist. For now, the problem is the quantity never update or changed.

I know this is not the best way for doing it but could any help me to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

This is my code currently

```
private void listOrder(String itemValue, String itemID)
{   
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    String quantity = "1";

    map.put(FOODID3, itemID);
    map.put(FOODNAME3, itemValue);  
    map.put(FOODQUANTITY3, quantity);

    boolean found = false;

    if (!LIST3.isEmpty())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < LIST3.size(); i++)
        {
            String exists = null;
            exists = LIST3.get(i).get(FOODID3).toString();

            if (exists.equals(itemID))
            {
                found=true;
                String b = map.get(FOODQUANTITY3);
                int quantityy = Integer.parseInt(b) +1;
                String c = Integer.toString(quantityy);
                System.out.println(c);
                map.put(FOODQUANTITY3, c); // I can't update the value here
                break;
            }
        }
    }               

    if (!found)
    {
        LIST3.add(map);
    }

    LISTORDER = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listOrder);

    List3Adapter adapter = new List3Adapter(MainActivity.this, LIST3);
    LISTORDER.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: what exactly is `LIST3`?

Comment: @SavTheCoder Sorry for no mentioned it clearly, LIST3 is ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> LIST3;

Comment: Can't you use `ArrayList.contains()` to check for existance of an object? http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains(java.lang.Object)

Comment: Does the control go inside this `if (exists.equals(itemID))` block?

Comment: @R.J Yes, everything is alright, just I cant update or change the value that is exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is if the key is found you are updating the new map that you created which is not stored in list3.

Try following code it will work:

```
private void listOrder(String itemValue, String itemID)
{   
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    String quantity = "1";

    map.put(FOODID3, itemID);
    map.put(FOODNAME3, itemValue);  
    map.put(FOODQUANTITY3, quantity);

    boolean found = false;

    if (!LIST3.isEmpty())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < LIST3.size(); i++)
        {
            String exists = null;
            exists = LIST3.get(i).get(FOODID3).toString();

            if (exists.equals(itemID))
            {
                found=true;
                String b = LIST3.get(i).get(FOODQUANTITY3);
                int quantityy = Integer.parseInt(b) +1;
                String c = Integer.toString(quantityy);
                System.out.println(c);
                LIST3.get(i).put(FOODQUANTITY3, c); // I can't update the value here
                break;
            }
        }
    }               

    if (!found)
    {
        LIST3.add(map);
    }

    LISTORDER = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listOrder);

    List3Adapter adapter = new List3Adapter(MainActivity.this, LIST3);
    LISTORDER.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: @vipul mittal :: good one bro.. i will vote up  this i like it

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println("start");
HashMap<String,String> a1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
a1.put("a1", "true");
a1.put("a1", "true2");
System.out.println("final value is ==" + a1.get("a1"));
```

I did this and I get `true2` so there is no prob to replace or override value in `HashMap`, just make some break point and check i think error is some other place may be the value which u want to enter is nor proper may be null check once.

**may be  if (exists.equals(itemID)) is always false just debug once**

Comment: @R.J So you think there is something wrong in if (exists.equals(itemID))?

Comment: Thanks for testing it

Comment: @user3040029 - I guess so. Is the value of `c` printed in the console?

Comment: @R.J Yes, even the value of b is printed in the console correctly

Comment: ohk just declare that HashMap to global once just do it i think it will be solved

Answer (score 0):

Just replace value like this

```
int position;

map.get(position).put("String");
```